# Are there any guarantees when modifying arguments during method invocation?

Tags: java, methods, jvm, arguments

In Java when passing arguments to a method and modifying the passed arguments *during* the method call is it guaranteed that the result is what is expected?
E.g.
`a.method(++i);`  etc

Is it **guaranteed** for instance that inside `method` the variable `i` will have the updated 
value?

Or `a.method(i++)` Will `method` get the value of `i` after incrementing or before?

Also same for all similar cases.
I kind of remember this is forbidden in C++ as implementation specific but perhaps I remember wrong.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java language specification for prefix/postfix increment/decrement operators:

- Prefix: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1.

> ... the value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into the variable ... The value of the prefix increment expression is the value of the
>   variable **after the new value is stored**.

- Postfix: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2

> ... the value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into the variable ... The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable **before the new value is stored**.

I think it's pretty clear. The function will get the incremented value in the prefix case, and not in the postfix case.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `++i` is evaluated *before* the method is called.

From the Java Language Specification's section ["Runtime evaluation of method invocation"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4):

> ... Second, the argument expressions are evaluated. ... Fifth, a new activation frame is created, synchronization is performed if necessary, and control is transferred to the method code.

And from the Java Language Specification's section ["Prefix increment operator"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1):

> The value of the prefix increment expression is the value of the variable after the new value is stored.

Answer (score 0):

No problem in Java, method will receive the updated value.

Comment: But how do you back this up?

Comment: It's a basic question about Java and you seem to have concerns coming from c++ experience. I didn't feel like needing back it up. I know that in Java thats guarantied and never failed to me or anyone I know in 8 years with Java.